# При optimistic locking не меняется значение столбика version в таблице

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lock

Для реализации оптимистических блокировок добавил поле с аннотацией @Version:

```
package com.example.my_api.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client {

    // ...

    @Version
    private Long version;

    // ...

}
```

В соответствующей таблице добавил столбик version. Далее тестирую Postman-ом. Сначала создаю нового клиента запросом POST, потом обновляю его данные (имя, возраст) запросом PUT. Если я правильно понял, то при обновлении сущности у нас автоматически должно увеличиваться значение поля version на единицу. Но в моём случае этого не происходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значение 0 и не увеличивается. Можете подсказать, в чём ошибка?

Comment: Видимо данные имеют другую область видимости, проверять надо сразу же после update.

Comment: @RomanC, в некоторых статьях фигурирует аннотация `@Lock`, но я так и не понял, в каких случаях она нужна. Может её куда-то навешать надо?